# How to use nested components defined as constant with arrow functions in React?

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

If I comment out `{children`} from Layout this works as expected.
Otherwise, error

> index.js Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children})

**Why?**

**layout.js**

```
const Layout = (children) => (<div>
  <Header />
  {children}
</div>)

export default Layout
```

**index.js** (root component)

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: It should be `props.children` and not `children` only. So probably destructure like `({ children })`. Read further [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(children) =>
```

Despite what you've called it, this is the entire props object, not just the children. Either use destructuring to pick the children prop:

```
({ children }) =>
```

Or access props.children explicitly:

```
(props) => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    {props.children}
  </div>
)
```